# accessing model object from view for MVC asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have this line of code within my .aspx file

```
<label title="<%= Model.ProductName %>"></label>
```

why is it when I run it, the label is not showing at all.

yet if I do something like this it would work:

```
<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName) %>
```

I would really like for the first method to work, is there a way?

thank you

Comment: go read up on the `label` HTML element. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you need to provide contents for this label:

```
<label title="some title" for="ProductName">
    <%: Model.ProductName %>
</label>
```

The way you wrote your markup the `<label>` tag is empty. Also make sure you properly HTML encode the contents. Notice in my example the usage of `<%:` (available only in ASP.NET 4) instead of `<%=`. If you are running on previous versions you could use the the following:

```
<label title="some title" for="ProductName">
    <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ProductName) %>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, there is another problem, is there a way to set the width for  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Synopsis, new { @class = "wide" })%> I tried adding the class in the css file, but didn't work

Comment: @Chen Lu, in your separate CSS file you could try defining the `wide` rule like this: `.wide { width: 200px; }`.

Comment: It worked out this way actually:  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Synopsis, new {style="width:300px"} )%> Thanks for your help!